# Правильная организация CLI+GUI-программы в Python

Tags: python, gui, pyinstaller

Есть небольшая *консольная* программка `program.py`. Необходимо прикрутить к ней GUI-интерфейс (`wx` достаточно).

Вопрос в следующем: как правильно организовать и разнести логику программы и ее интерфейс? С учетом того, что она будет преобразована в единый bundle с помощью *PyInstaller*. Хочется сделать цивилизованным способом.

Сейчас я вижу это так: есть файл со всей логикой и функциями `program_lib.py`. Далее, есть исполняющий файл `run_program.py`, который импортирует необходимую логику из `program_lib.py`, и, например, по умолчанию запускает GUI, а при указании ключа `--cli` запускает консольный интерфейс. Я в верном направлении думаю?

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно, например, весь вывод из stdout и stderr перенаправить в красивое окошко вашего приложения, а не консоль.

Comment: @m9_psy это за рамками вопроса, и с этим проблем как бы не предвидится :)